# What are standard names for JUnit and TestNG "before" and "after" annotated methods?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng

What are standard names for JUnit and TestNG "before" and "after" annotated methods?  Is this kind of thing standardized in the industry at all?

I am trying to guess at what names I should generally use and I came up with this. Can anyone improve on this?   Would you say these are just fine?

```
 *   BeforeTest - setUpTest 
 *   AfterTest - cleanUpTest
 *   BeforeMethod - setUpMethod
 *   AfterMethod - cleanUpMethod
 *   BeforeClass - static setUpClass
 *   AfterClass - static tearDownClass
 *   BeforeSuite - static setUpSuite
 *   AfterSuite - static tearDownSuite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also name methods after what they do, and not after when they run: `populateTestDatabase()`, `prepareMocks()`, whatever. The annotation already tells when the method runs.